# Why does this integral change depending on whether I assign $n$ a value first?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

I have an integral I wish to compute in Mathematica:
[image]
As you can see, if I evaluate this integral and then try to evaluate the result for $n=2$, the expression is undefined. If I substitute $n=2$ and then evaluate the integral, I get a well-defined value. Why is this?

Comment: Please, do not post images of your code, copy-paste it into the edit window of your question by using the icon “{}”...

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GenericAndNonGenericCases.html

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, the integrated result(cn) is indeterminate($\frac{0}{0}$) at n=2. You should therefore take the limit:

```
In[133]:= Limit[cn, n -> 2]

Out[133]= 1/Sqrt[2]
```